# Keras: Error when downloading Fashion_MNIST Data

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to download data from Fashion MNIST, but it produces an error. Originally, it was downloading and working properly, but I had to terminate it because I had to turn off my computer. Once I opened the file up again, it gives me an error. I'm not sure what the problem is, but is it because I already downloaded some parts of the data once, and keras doesn't recognize that? I am using Jupyter notebook in a conda environment

Here is the link to the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLGDm.png

Answer (score 4):

You have missed adding `tf.` to the line

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
```

The below code works perfectly for me. Importing the `fashion_mnist` dataset has been outlined in `tensorflow` documention [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/load_data).

Change your code to:

```
import tensorflow as tf

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

or, use the better way to do it below. This avoids creating an extra variable `fashion_mnist`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I am using tensorflow 1.9.0, keras 2.2.2 and python 3.6.6 on Windows 10 x64 OS.

Comment: I tried your way, but I still keep getting the same error.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of tensorflow and python you are using? Also what is your OS? Have you tried reinstalling or upgrading tensorflow and Jupyter notebook? Have you tried executing the code using IDLE just to see if the error persists? The code I have provided works perfectly for me in both `Spyder` and `IDLE`.

Comment: I tried reinstalling and upgrading tensorflow and Jupyter notebook, but it still produces the same error. I am using tensorflow 1.10.0, keras 2.2.2 and python 3.6.5 on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I know my pc well, I can't download anything larger than 2.7 MB (in terminal), due to `WinError 8`.

So I manually downloaded all packs from storage.google (since some packs are 25 MB).

Check the packs:

[image]

then I paste all packs to `\datasets\fashion-mnist`

The next time u run your code, it should be fixed.

Note : If u have VScode then just CTRL and click the link, then you can download it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error regarding the cURL connection, and by looking into the error message I was able to track the file where the URL was declared. In my case it was:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py
```

At line 44 I have commented out the line:

```
# base = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/'
```

And declared a different base URL, which I had found looking into the [documentation](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist#get-the-data) of the original dataset:

```
base = 'http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/'
```

The download started immediately and gave no errors. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for some reason you have an incomplete download for the MNIST dataset.

You will have to manually delete the downloaded folder which usually resides in ~/.keras/datasets or any path specified by you relative to this path, in your case MNIST_data.

Go to : C:\Users\Username.keras\datasets

and then Delete the Dataset that you want to redownload or has the error

You should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually add print for the path from which it is taking dataset ..
Ex: print(paths) in file **fashion_mnist.py**

```
with gzip.open(paths[3], 'rb') as imgpath:
    print(paths)  #debug print in fashion_mnist.py 
    x_test = np.frombuffer(
        imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_test), 28, 28)
```

& from this path, remove the files & this will start to download fresh data ..

Answer (score -2):

Change The base address with 'http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/' as described previously. It works for me.
I was getting error of `Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AsadA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 448, in load
    return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
EOFError: Ran out of input
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AsadA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 450, in load
    raise IOError(
OSError: Failed to interpret file 'C:\\Users\\AsadA\\.keras\\datasets\\mnist.npz' as a pickle"**
```

GO TO FILE `C:\Users\AsadA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets` (In my Case) and follow the instructions:

Comment: where are the instuctions?