# URL error 403 while load data from keras fashion_mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I have the following error every time.
just want to load fashion_mnist.

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(x_train_full, y_train_full), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

> URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz: 403 -- Forbidden

version : 2.4.0
python3

or how can I load this dataset manually?

Comment: no problem with tf.keras.datasets.boston_housing and tf.keras.datasets.reuters

Comment: I add  tf.  but it didnt work

Comment: If you click on the URL, can you download it with a browser? Because I can and it makes me think this is a localized internet connection problem.

Comment: yes I can. it also would be helpful if I know how to load data manually.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question and answer: [Keras: Error when downloading Fashion_MNIST Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664127/keras-error-when-downloading-fashion-mnist-data)

So, change your code to (add TensorFlow import):

```
import tensorflow as tf

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

Additional: I can execute this by using Python 3.7.7 and TensorFlow 2.3.0

Comment: I did it before asking but it didnt work.

Comment: I can execute the mentioned code and load the data by using Python 3.7.7
and TensorFlow 2.3.0 version in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I have no problem with two other datasets as mentioned in question. I have no idea.

Comment: Well, in my case, everything is loaded perfectly...maybe you can try to change your Python and TF versions?